# Does Blender have a tool to automatically create & set up a control panel for a character's expressions?

Tags: animation, rigging

Can Blender automatically create a control driver panel for animating and controlling a character's facial expressions? The expressions are all shape key driven.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a tool built-in into Blender. There is an option to use custom-properties to drive shape keys though. It is not as good as a python scripted interface, but does the job for small rigs.

https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/custom_properties.html